# How to print the entire row from a file using the user input

Tags: python

I have a script where I can print the user input value from a file but not the output that I want to see.

the file looks like this:

```
1.1.1.0     test
1.1.1.1     test1
1.1.1.2     test2
1.1.1.3     test3
1.1.1.4     test4
1.1.1.5     test5
1.1.1.6     test6
1.1.1.7     test7
1.1.1.8     test8
```

**PROBLEM 1:**

In the if statement inside the for loop, if I use `in`, it will print the line when the input value is equal to eg: "test4" - this output is correct:

```
Enter text here: test4
1.1.1.4     test4
```

However, if the input is equal to `test`, it will print all the values that has "test" in it:

```
fopen = open('sample.txt',mode='r+')
fread = fopen.readlines()

ui = input("Enter text here: ")

for line in fread:
    if ui in line:
        print(line)

fopen.close()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Enter text here: test
1.1.1.0     test

1.1.1.1     test1

1.1.1.2     test2

1.1.1.3     test3

1.1.1.4     test4

1.1.1.5     test5

1.1.1.6     test6

1.1.1.7     test7

1.1.1.8     test8
```

How can I address this problem?

**PROBLEM 2:**

In the if statement inside the for loop, if I use `==`, it will not print **anything**...grrr!

```
fopen = open('sample.txt',mode='r+')
fread = fopen.readlines()
    
ui = input("Enter text here: ")

for line in fread:
    if ui == line:
        print(line)
                                               
fopen.close()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Enter text here: test
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `in` performs a substring search. `==` compares the entire values. You want to compare one of the words on the line. To do this, first you need to *determine what that word is*, and then compare the entire word.

Comment: ohh I see...that make sense, so my `==` is false because the user input is incomplete or not True that why its not returning output.

Comment: You don't really need `fread`. You can just do `for line in fopen` for the exact same effect. And you should also use the `with` context manager (as I showed you in your other question)

Comment: this community is AWESOME!! you guys are the best! thank you so much for helping me understand and make things much clearer... high5 to all!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a list of the *words* in that line, and then check if the input is in that list:

```py
with open('sample.txt', mode='r+') as fopen:
    for line in fopen:
        if ui in line.split():
            print(line)
```

Magically, this solves both of your problems, if the input is `test`, you will not print lines with `test4` for example.

---

The trick is using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> line = "1.1.1 test3"
>>> splt = line.split()
>>> splt
['1.1.1', 'test3']
>>> "test" in splt
False
>>> "test3" in splt
True
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use endswith() function

```
for line in fread:
    if line.endswith(f"{ui}\n"):
        print(line)
```

the output is like:

```
➜  ~ python3 script.py 
Enter text here: test
1.1.1.0     test

➜  ~ python3 script.py
Enter text here: test3
1.1.1.3     test3

➜  ~ python3 script.py
Enter text here: test2
1.1.1.2     test2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on whitespace and perform `==` operation to check the user input.

```
fopen = open('tmp.txt',mode='r+')
fread = fopen.readlines()

ui=input("Enter text here: ")

for line in fread:
    # split on whitespace
    value, key = line.split()
    if ui == key:
        print(line)
fopen.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You were forgetting to check against each word in the line, and instead were checking if the key was in the line at all as a substring. You need to make sure you split the line(string) and then check against every element to make sure your key matches an item. Using the `in` keyword will then do what you expect, as you are comparing 2 objects to check if their values are equal. It would be the same as doing a for loop on the split list, then using == to check if key and i are the same.

```
fopen = open('sample.txt',mode='r+')
fread = fopen.readlines()

ui=input("Enter text here: ")

for line in fread:
    if ui in line.split():
        print(line)

fopen.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to keep the lines which last word IS exactly what's the user input.

Try this:

```
ui=input("Enter text here: ")
with open('sample.txt',mode='r+') as stream:
    for line in stream:  # Yes looping over a text file yields lines
        words = line.split()  # "xx  yy  zz ".split() -> ["xx", "yy", "zz"]
        if words[-1] == ui:  # Compare with last word
            print(line)

# You don't need to close the file, you used it in a context mgr ("with ...")
```